Question on READ COMMITTED isolation level
I am trying to understand READ COMMITTED isolation level.
Let's say I have an open transaction that has made some inserts and updates to a table (let's call this update-transaction). Now if I start another transaction, while the update transaction is still running, that runs a SELECT * on this table (let's call this the select-transaction), my understanding is that it will block, because it does not want to return uncommitted data.
But what if I had the SELECT * query started, and is still running, before the update-transaction started? Let's say the table has millions of rows, so the SELECT query takes a minute to run. Will the inserts and updates from the other update-transaction block?
If it's not blocked, and the update-transaction eventually commits, while the select is still running. Now will the select return the committed values?
(This question occurred to me when I was watching this video on SQL Server isolation levels)

I see. Okay done. Thank you. I though the concept might be similar so tagged multiple dbms, but I've fixed it now.

The blocked SELECT query has a timeout - if the update transaction completes before the timeout expires, then the SELECT query will go ahead and return all the data (including the updated and committed data). If the update transaction doesn't complete in time, the SELECT query will fail with a timeout and not return anything.

You can also instruct your SELECT query to just simply ignore blocked rows and return the other, by using the WITH READPAST query hint. See the MS documentation on this table hint for additional info

There's also the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isolation, which would mean the 2 queries don't block each other, and the SELECT would only return data as it appeared when the query started.

Have you read Paul White's excellent article? https://www.sql.kiwi/2014/04/the-read-committed-isolation-level/ It basically depends where the SELECT is up to. It locks and unlocks pages or rows as it goes along, so it will only get blocked while the update is actually running, and only if it hits that page/row. This is not really what most people expect, as you could get duplicate rows. (If one query or the other takes a table/partition lock then the other will be completely blocked immediately).

@marc_s thanks. I wonder what the timeout typically is - in the order of seconds? minutes? I bet it's configurable.

@ThomA thank you - yea, snapshot isolation is the next thing I am going to try and understand.

@Charlieface Thank you as well. The article looks good - will read through it. So let's say there are 2000 rows. The SELECT query has read the first 1000 rows, and before it reads the next 1000 the update query commits and has made changes to all 2000 rows, it's possible that for the remaining 1000 the SELECT returns the updated rows? Looks like it.

If the update is scanning/seeking in the same order as the select then it will depend on which one started first, the other will just get blocked behind it. But say the select is scanning the whole table and the update only updates one row: yes, the select could return either the old or new version (once committed) and will only be blocked if it happens to be reading that exact row. If the row gets moved in the index that the select is reading then it may get read twice or not at all.
